# Using setmonofont with Bera Sans Mono in Beamer produces garbled output

Tags: beamer, listings, fontspec

I am using Bera Sans Mono as the monospaced font for typesetting code listings using the `listings` package. This is done for slides which are produced using `beamer` and XeLaTeX. My preamble includes the following (which used to work before a recent update to the MikTeX engine, the fontspec package, and the above-mentioned packages):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{Bera Sans Mono}[Scale=0.9] % for code listings beramono is used
\newfontfamily\quotefont{Linux Libertine O}[Ligatures=TeX] % selects Libertine for quotation marks
```

The output produced is:
[image: Garbled code listing]

If I do not use `\setmonofont` and have the following preamble instead, the correct output is produced:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newfontfamily\quotefont{Linux Libertine O}[Ligatures=TeX] % selects Libertine for quotation marks
```

[image: Correct code listing]

Why am I unable to use `\setmonofont{Bera Sans Mono}[Scale=0.9]` (which used to work before)?

Some additional points to note:

1. XeLaTeX is able to find the font
2. `\setmonofont` appears to work correctly with other fonts, just not Bera Sans Mono.

Comment: A minimal (non) working example?

Comment: Probably xetex and/or xdvipdfmx is finding a wrong font. This can happen if there are two versions of a font on a system. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to your document, and then compile on the command line with `xelatex --nopdf file` and `xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv` then the log and the terminal output will show the pathes of the fonts used.

Comment: I should have checked first. There is  no opentype font "bera sans mono", it is a type1 font. You shouldn't load it with \setmonofont`.Try `\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}[Scale=0.9]` instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! Your suggestion to use the Bitstream font worked and helped to clear up some misunderstandings on my part. Do you want to post this as a formal answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no opentype font `Bera Sans Mono`, xelatex finds the normal type1 version and as it is not unicode encoded you get garbage.

To quote the CTAN info (http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bera)

> The Bera fam­ily is a repack­ag­ing, for use with TEX, of the Bit­stream Vera fam­ily.

So with xelatex you should use

```
\setmonofont{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}
```