# DejaVu Sans Mono does not work with setmonofont and XeLaTex, UTF 8

Tags: fonts, xetex, typewriter

When I use DejaVu Sans Mono as a mono font, I get wrong output. I realize my problem is related to [this questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264356/using-setmonofont-with-bera-sans-mono-in-beamer-produces-garbled-output), but I don't know how to fix it.

MWE:

```
\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}

\begin{document}

\texttt{Hello, World!}

\end{document}
```

Output:

> Ifmmp- Xpsme"

Log with `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1`

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99992 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2015.9.28)  28 MAR 2017 11:27
entering extended mode
**mwe.tex
(mwe.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script document class (article)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\scrkbase.sty"
Package: scrkbase 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent b
asics and keyval usage)

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\scrbase.sty"
Package: scrbase 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\scrlfile.sty"
Package: scrlfile 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (loading files)

Package scrlfile, 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm

))) ("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\tocbasic.sty"
Package: tocbasic 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
)
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `toc'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `toc' on input line 123.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lof'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lof' on input line 124.
Package tocbasic Info: omitting babel extension for `lot'
(tocbasic)             because of feature `nobabel' available
(tocbasic)             for `lot' on input line 125.
Class scrartcl Info: File `scrsize11pt.clo' used instead of
(scrartcl)           file `scrsize11.clo' to setup font sizes on input line 202
7.

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\scrsize11pt.clo"
File: scrsize11pt.clo 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script font size class option (11pt
)
Requested font "cmr10" at 10.95pt
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\koma-script\typearea.sty"
Package: typearea 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (type area)

Package typearea, 2015/07/02 v3.18 KOMA-Script package (type area)
                  Copyright (C) Frank Neukam, 1992-1994
                  Copyright (C) Markus Kohm, 1994-

\ta@bcor=\skip41
\ta@div=\count79
\ta@hblk=\skip42
\ta@vblk=\skip43
\ta@temp=\skip44
\footheight=\skip45
Package typearea Info: These are the values describing the layout:
(typearea)             DIV  = 10
(typearea)             BCOR = 0.0pt
(typearea)             \paperwidth      = 597.50793pt
(typearea)              \textwidth      = 418.25555pt
(typearea)              DIV departure   = -6%
(typearea)              \evensidemargin = 17.3562pt
(typearea)              \oddsidemargin  = 17.3562pt
(typearea)             \paperheight     = 845.04694pt
(typearea)              \textheight     = 595.80026pt
(typearea)              \topmargin      = -25.16531pt
(typearea)              \headheight     = 17.0pt
(typearea)              \headsep        = 20.40001pt
(typearea)              \topskip        = 11.0pt
(typearea)              \footskip       = 47.6pt
(typearea)              \baselineskip   = 13.6pt
(typearea)              on input line 1506.
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsubscript on input line 3836.
\abovecaptionskip=\skip46
\belowcaptionskip=\skip47
\c@pti@nb@sid@b@x=\box26
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.sty"
Package: fontspec 2015/07/22 v2.4d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3.sty"
Package: expl3 2015/09/27 v6111 L3 programming layer (loader) 

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\l3kernel\expl3-code.tex"
Package: expl3 2015/09/27 v6111 L3 programming layer (code) 
L3 Module: l3bootstrap 2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Bootstrap code
L3 Module: l3names 2015/09/27 v6108 L3 Namespace for primitives
L3 Module: l3basics 2015/09/22 v6033 L3 Basic definitions
L3 Module: l3expan 2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Argument expansion
L3 Module: l3tl 2015/09/23 v6037 L3 Token lists
L3 Module: l3str 2015/09/20 v6021 L3 Strings
L3 Module: l3seq 2015/08/05 v5777 L3 Sequences and stacks
L3 Module: l3int 2015/09/25 v6089 L3 Integers
\c_max_int=\count88
\l_tmpa_int=\count89
\l_tmpb_int=\count90
\g_tmpa_int=\count91
\g_tmpb_int=\count92
L3 Module: l3quark 2015/08/17 v5855 L3 Quarks
L3 Module: l3prg 2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Control structures
\g__prg_map_int=\count93
L3 Module: l3clist 2015/09/02 v5901 L3 Comma separated lists
L3 Module: l3token 2015/09/23 v6040 L3 Experimental token manipulation
L3 Module: l3prop 2015/08/05 v5777 L3 Property lists
L3 Module: l3msg 2015/09/23 v6037 L3 Messages
L3 Module: l3file 2015/09/23 v6037 L3 File and I/O operations
\l_iow_line_count_int=\count94
\l__iow_target_count_int=\count95
\l__iow_current_line_int=\count96
\l__iow_current_word_int=\count97
\l__iow_current_indentation_int=\count98
L3 Module: l3skip 2015/09/25 v6089 L3 Dimensions and skips
\c_zero_dim=\dimen103
\c_max_dim=\dimen104
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen108
\c_zero_skip=\skip48
\c_max_skip=\skip49
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip50
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip51
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip52
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip53
\c_zero_muskip=\muskip10
\c_max_muskip=\muskip11
\l_tmpa_muskip=\muskip12
\l_tmpb_muskip=\muskip13
\g_tmpa_muskip=\muskip14
\g_tmpb_muskip=\muskip15
L3 Module: l3keys 2015/09/23 v6037 L3 Key-value interfaces
\g__keyval_level_int=\count99
\l_keys_choice_int=\count100
L3 Module: l3fp 2015/08/25 v5890 L3 Floating points
\c__fp_leading_shift_int=\count101
\c__fp_middle_shift_int=\count102
\c__fp_trailing_shift_int=\count103
\c__fp_big_leading_shift_int=\count104
\c__fp_big_middle_shift_int=\count105
\c__fp_big_trailing_shift_int=\count106
\c__fp_Bigg_leading_shift_int=\count107
\c__fp_Bigg_middle_shift_int=\count108
\c__fp_Bigg_trailing_shift_int=\count109
L3 Module: l3box 2015/08/09 v5822 L3 Experimental boxes
\c_empty_box=\box27
\l_tmpa_box=\box28
\l_tmpb_box=\box29
\g_tmpa_box=\box30
\g_tmpb_box=\box31
L3 Module: l3coffins 2015/08/06 v5789 L3 Coffin code layer
\l__coffin_internal_box=\box32
\l__coffin_internal_dim=\dimen109
\l__coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen110
\l__coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen111
\l__coffin_x_dim=\dimen112
\l__coffin_y_dim=\dimen113
\l__coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen114
\l__coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen115
\c_empty_coffin=\box33
\l__coffin_aligned_coffin=\box34
\l__coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box35
\l_tmpa_coffin=\box36
\l_tmpb_coffin=\box37
\l__coffin_display_coffin=\box38
\l__coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box39
\l__coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box40
\l__coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen116
\l__coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen117
\l__coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen118
L3 Module: l3color 2014/08/23 v5354 L3 Experimental color support
L3 Module: l3candidates 2015/09/23 v6039 L3 Experimental additions to l3kernel
\l__box_top_dim=\dimen119
\l__box_bottom_dim=\dimen120
\l__box_left_dim=\dimen121
\l__box_right_dim=\dimen122
\l__box_top_new_dim=\dimen123
\l__box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen124
\l__box_left_new_dim=\dimen125
\l__box_right_new_dim=\dimen126
\l__box_internal_box=\box41
\l__coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen127
\l__coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen128
\l__coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen129
\l__coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen130
\l__coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l__coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen132
\l__coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen133
L3 Module: l3sys 2015/09/25 v6087 L3 Experimental system/runtime functions
L3 Module: l3luatex 2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3unicode-data.def"
File: l3unicode-data.def 2015/07/20 v5676 L3 Unicode data
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3xdvipdfmx.def"
File: l3xdvidpfmx.def 2015/09/10 v5983 L3 Experimental driver: xdvipdfmx
))
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\l3packages\xparse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2015/09/27 v6111 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l__xparse_current_arg_int=\count110
\l__xparse_m_args_int=\count111
\l__xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count112
\l__xparse_processor_int=\count113
\l__xparse_v_nesting_int=\count114
)
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count115
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count116
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count117
\l__fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen134
\l__fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen135
\l__fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen136

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-patches.sty"
Package: fontspec-patches 2015/07/22 v2.4d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 49.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 57.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 60.
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/redefine-command"
. 
. Redefining command \oldstylenums with sig. 'm' on line 155.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \liningnums with sig. 'm' on line 159.
.................................................
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2015/07/22 v2.4d Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTe
X

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def"
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 105.


("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
Requested font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
Requested font "[lmromanslant10-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmromanslant10-regular.otf
Requested font "[lmroman10-italic]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-italic.otf
Requested font "[lmroman10-bold]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-bold.otf
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
Requested font "[lmsans10-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmsans10-regular.otf
)
\tipaTiiicode=\count118
\tipasavetokens=\toks15
\tipachecktokens=\toks16

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 94.

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2015/09/11 v4.06 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen137
\Gin@req@width=\dimen138
))
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \__fontspec_post_arg:w with sig. 'mmO{}' on line 42.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \fontspec with sig. 'om' on line 44.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmainfont with sig. 'om' on line 54.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setsansfont with sig. 'om' on line 64.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmonofont with sig. 'om' on line 74.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 88.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setboldmathrm with sig. 'om' on line 96.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathsf with sig. 'om' on line 104.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \setmathtt with sig. 'om' on line 112.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfamily with sig. 'mom' on line 126.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontface with sig. 'mom' on line 141.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \defaultfontfeatures with sig. 't+om' on line 155.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \addfontfeatures with sig. 'm' on line 210.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 221.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newAATfeature with sig. 'mmmm' on line 229.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newopentypefeature with sig. 'mmm' on line 237.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeature with sig. 'mm' on line 261.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \aliasfontfeatureoption with sig. 'mmm' on line 270.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontscript with sig. 'mm' on line 275.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \newfontlanguage with sig. 'mm' on line 301.
.................................................
.................................................
. LaTeX info: "xparse/define-command"
. 
. Defining command \DeclareFontsExtensions with sig. 'm' on line 321.
.................................................
\l__fontspec_tmp_int=\count119
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 2230.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 2235.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 2240.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 2245.

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\fontspec\fontspec.cfg")))
\g__file_internal_ior=\read1
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
.................................................
. fontspec info: "no-scripts"
. 
. Font DejaVu Sans Mono does not contain any OpenType `Script' information.
.................................................
\g__fontspec_family_DejaVuSansMono_int=\count120
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/BI/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldObliqu
e.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/B/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/I/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.pf
b
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
Requested font "[lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text" at 10.95pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/B/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/B/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Bold.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/I/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.pf
b
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/I/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-Oblique.pf
b
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/BI/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldObliqu
e.pfb
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/BI/OT" at 10.0pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono-BoldObliqu
e.pfb
.................................................
. fontspec info: "defining-font"
. 
. Font family 'DejaVuSansMono(0)' created for font 'DejaVu Sans Mono' with
. options [WordSpace={1,0,0},PunctuationSpace=WordSpace].
. 
. This font family consists of the following shapes:
. 
. * 'normal' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVu Sans Mono/OT:"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font 
. 
. * 'bold' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVu Sans Mono/B/OT:"
. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font 
. 
. * 'italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVu Sans Mono/I/OT:"
. 
. * 'small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font 
. 
. * 'bold italic' with NFSS spec.:
. <->"DejaVu Sans Mono/BI/OT:"
. 
. * 'bold small caps' with NFSS spec.:
. 
. and font adjustment code:
. \fontdimen 2\font =1\fontdimen 2\font \fontdimen 3\font =0\fontdimen 3\font
. \fontdimen 4\font =0\fontdimen 4\font \fontdimen 7\font =0\fontdimen 2\font 
.................................................
 (mwe.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T3/cmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for T3+cmr on input line 10.

("C:\Other\MiKTeX 2.9 x32\tex\latex\tipa\t3cmr.fd"
File: t3cmr.fd 2001/12/31 TIPA font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 10.
.................................................
. fontspec info: "setup-math"
. 
. Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
.................................................
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/DejaVuSansMono(0)/m/n on input lin
e 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/DejaVuSansMono(0)/bx/n on input li
ne 10.
Requested font "DejaVu Sans Mono/OT:" at 10.95pt
 -> C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb
 [1

] (mwe.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 15607 strings out of 428764
 319390 string characters out of 3164386
 395653 words of memory out of 3000000
 18901 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 4036 words of font info for 27 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1096 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 61i,6n,61p,10354b,218s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on mwe.xdv (1 page, 760 bytes).
```

Comment: I have no problem.

Comment: Such shifts normally mean that you have two versions of the font and xetex or xdvipdfmx is finding the wrong one. Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to your document, and then compile on the command line with `xelatex --nopdf` file and `xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv` then the log and the terminal output will show the pathes of the fonts used.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer xelatex  fails with `--nopdf` but I hope the log-file is still helpful

Comment: Sorry it should be `--no-pdf`. Put `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` at the begin of the document (before \documentclass.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer done

Comment: As you can see in your log-file, xelatex is loading a  type1 fonts: `C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb`. Your system is rather old, imho a newer xetex would prefer the ttf (it does for me). If you don't want to update load the font by file name with `\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! Explicitly specifying the ttf worked. Now that I have updated my XeTeX, the MWE also works.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some ideas about the real fonts used by `xelatex` by adding `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to your document. You can also compile on the command line with

```
  xelatex --no-pdf file
  xdvipdfmx -vv file.xdv
```

which will tell you also about the fonts used by xdvipdfmx.

In your case one can see in the log-file that xelatex is loading a type1 font with extension `.pfb`:

```
   C:/Other/MiKTeX 2.9 x32/fonts/type1/public/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.pfb.
```

Your system is rather old, imho a newer xetex would prefer the `.ttf` (it does for me). If you don't want to update load the font by file name with

```
  \setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono.ttf}
```